# Do I need to create multiple database connection in a loop?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using sqllite3 and want to insert data into the table. My code roughly looks like:

```
def fill_database(db):
     ...
    for record in records:
       add_to_db(db, record)
 ...

def add_to_db(db, record):
   ...
   connection = sqlite3.connect(db)
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   cursor.execute("...")
   connection.commit()
   connection.close()
```

As it can be seen, the database is connected and closed for each insertion of the data record. Is there a way to only connect and close the db once for all the data to be processed?

Comment: Normally you'd open the database, and use that handle for the lifetime of your program. What you have is the worst case workflow if you care about performance at all.

Comment: So I can create the 'connection' before the 'for' loop and pass it as a parameter to the add_to_db() function?

Comment: You'd want to pass a cursor instead and use a single transaction for all the inserts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code works on multithreading or multiprocessing. Connection pool involved will be more efficient. Definition from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)

> In software engineering, a connection pool is a cache of database
>   connections maintained so that the connections can be reused when
>   future requests to the database are required. Connection pools are
>   used to enhance the performance of executing commands on a database.

Below is an exmaple from [sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html). The pool manage all connections automatically, and you don't need to create a new connection when you need to execute SQL.

```
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool

import psycopg2

def getconn():
    c = psycopg2.connect(username='ed', host='127.0.0.1', dbname='test')
    return c

mypool = pool.QueuePool(getconn, max_overflow=10, pool_size=5)


def fill_database(db):
     ...
    for record in records:
       add_to_db(db, record)
 ...

def add_to_db(db, record):
   ...
   connection = mypool.connect()
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   cursor.execute("...")
   connection.commit()
   connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot more efficient. Committing data after each record hurts performance a lot.

```
def fill_database(db):
    ...
    connection = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    for record in records:
        cursor.execute("...")

    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

If you must have a separate function then pass the cursor as an argument instead of the db.

Answer (score 1):

It better to open the database once in the beginning and close it at the end by Createing a global varible.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(db)
cursor = connection.cursor()
def fill_database():
     ...
    for record in records:
       add_to_db(record)
 ...

def add_to_dbrecord):
   ..
   cursor.execute("...")
   connection.commit()

#end of script
connection.close()
```

you can use Singleton Design Pattern if you are using classes
Hope it helps